# Folium PolyLine not showing up on map - folium 0.7.0 with python 3.6 (anaconda) in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, networkx, folium

I have a folium map of a neighborhood in New York City generated using the following code:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[40.7035, -73.990], 
               zoom_start=16.5,
               tiles='cartodbpositron')
```

I then try to add lines connecting points on the map using `folium.PolyLine()`, but even though I see them listed when I call `m._children`, they don't show up on the map.

Here's the code to create the lines, where G is a networkx graph:

```
for x, y in G.edges():
    points = [nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'loc')[x], nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'loc')[y]]
    egde = folium.PolyLine(locations=points, weight=5, color='red')
    edge.add_to(m)
```

A sample `point`:

```
[(-73.986635, 40.703988), (-73.988683, 40.702674)]
```

Output of `m.children` (first few lines):

```
OrderedDict([('cartodbpositron',
              <folium.raster_layers.TileLayer at 0x12279feb8>),
             ('poly_line_ae5785771a2148c5a8559cb0085b10a4',
              <folium.vector_layers.PolyLine at 0x122892128>),
             ('poly_line_ee73b495559940d484064e8c8492eda5',
              <folium.vector_layers.PolyLine at 0x1229734a8>),
             ('poly_line_415a7ed70a2a425e876c8a6711408a6a', ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: folium polyline expects `y, x` and you're passing `x, y`

Comment: Wow I'm surprised I didn't catch that. Thanks @BobHaffner!

Comment: No problem.  That one hasn't gotten me a couple of times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of odd that folium polyline expects coordinates in `[latitude, longitude]` format, whereas in general accepted format is `[longitude, latitude]`.

Let's take an example:
I'm assuming you are using OSRM to get geometries.

OSRM geometries returns coordinates in the form of `[[longitude,latitude],...]`.

If you'll directly use them with folium, it'll not show the polyline.

Reverse the geometry coordinates using following function:

```py
def reverse_lon_lat(x):
    a = [[p[1], p[0]] for p in x]
    return a
```

and draw the polylines you intend to.

Answer (score 0):

This is because folium expects coords in `[latitude, longitude]` format. And if you have data in `[longitude, latitude]`, then you can use the below helper function.

```
PATHC = [
    [90.422974, 23.825237],
    [90.419884, 23.82084],
    [90.410957, 23.816757],
    [90.404778, 23.812046],
    [90.402031, 23.803879],
    [90.401001, 23.792884],
    [90.398941, 23.780946],
    [90.395851, 23.770578],
    [90.394821, 23.762723],
    [90.394478, 23.759267],
]
PATHC = list(map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]], PATHC))
```